# How To subclass a wxpython StaticBitmap to add an attribute

Tags: wxpython, subclass, super

I'm trying to add an "value" attribute to a wxpython static bitmap but I can't figure how to instantiate the subclass I create. When I try to create it I get the error 'Expected a 2-tuple of integers or a wxPoint object.'

Can anyone tell what I'm missing?

Thanks

```
class StaticBmpButton(wx.StaticBitmap):
    def __init__(self, parent,id,bmp_off,bmp_on,bmp_over):
        super(wx.StaticBitmap,self).__init__(parent,id,bitmap)
        self.value=False
```

Comment: Just for the record: As coded above, an attempt to create a StaticBmbButton() object will try to run the wx.StaticBitmap.__init__() function, but the bitmap parameter is not defined. The function expects a wx.Size() parameter at this position, which is a tuple of two integers, and thus results in the error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are creating your own custom button? You may want to create it as a PyControl. I created a fadebutton using this method and can import it as a custom control and direct replacement for a wx.Button.

```
class StaticBmpButton(wx.PyControl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="", pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.NO_BORDER, validator=wx.DefaultValidator, name="StaticBmpButton"):
        wx.PyControl.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=id, pos=pos, size=size, style=wx.NO_BORDER, validator=validator, name=name)
```

Here is a link to the basic framework of a custom PyContol button:
http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=17567
I can't get python-forum to load right now. If you need me to post the code from that page, let me know.

Edit: I guess python-forum doesn't exist anymore. Here's a link to the cached page:
http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=BlockButton.py+gradient&d=4580007883572708&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=7g-uOMgExcAivyB_VE3bzv2kstr-ww21

Edit to show example:

This is just a quick example of how you could use bitmaps in the PyControl framework. There are probably better ways to do this, but it will show you the idea. Sorry the code is so long, but I wanted to embed the images so it would be easier to demo.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
from wx.lib.embeddedimage import PyEmbeddedImage

button_blue = PyEmbeddedImage(
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAAaCAIAAADOqG6yAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAFxklE"
    "QVRYhd2Yz4sdRRDHq7p7ZjdZiCg5aRAVRaMg4kHWgyjk5sGbJ/Hqf+D/IvgHiFfRq+hVA6IG"
    "PARhJSIuYjTZvH07b7qrPMx0d1V373vP3ewlnex7/aOmp+sz36ruecjMAAAARDSs/N/3FrcP"
    "Dn/45c7vf95dDuPoKRk88sUY7Jy9vNs/c+3q69effvba1cev7PWdMcZMBni8XN28dfDJ599+"
    "//OBD2Gnd5d3+71LvXPGID6MNSDg9JV7MI5UVqJdfTVWI1eYZyjXreZC9YGVHRMMo7+/OLl/"
    "tDxZ+Z2+e+eNFz96/62Xn38SP/j405u3DsYxdA53O4OInngYKdB5BIXFInDqmVYTe5QLsZWu"
    "jPZ5KuEcKkfbZtmmfE71qJ7aGuwdWgMh8D9Hw+Jk3LvUv/v2q+72b4c+EAOMPozeAwCDaT7F"
    "TXhKuWi/gWMPtmyURDZNJWdrmjUF1xhFnKfSMwSCk1UAYArkAwHAaqQ/Dv91aVIG08ZwSkGx"
    "ojVebetSMzRRCWP9Hf8XoPUzICKABYAQvBcRlmFtLOenUy1ImdWziWC9EDpysPIDiHgYRiJK"
    "xpthbeNV0+zMIbb+jsIc14xuraD2jZh5OYzD6OezAAI0YV10fK2ZaoNvF0lHmhHxg+NhOayK"
    "U5OClRLwRq/ODugMs50vAW1cTzHbsPJHixPvQzJgAGAGCQun/6fk1EeYzmTGDMMwPjgeRoGp"
    "KEJZiGiqVZ55TVsAkrPVgE7z6rT1bBlixVTMsBr9YjkMo4dNJ0uhLAREPD+d9WYPe4Mvb968"
    "kZqNwRMNq3F5MvoQtn6XQ9A5a8JVuXSRgGo6YgZxn+0CeUouDEDExPOR0gcKgUIgOtdLbpWz"
    "DALghifWii+c1sgMxEw81VNarOZi3SUlAAhFMLC6oHKXxQfH4fnmtcdnK2mVOgxNK3cgzqdD"
    "RARk5kAciJimsy0iyrc9AwBomtJsBFejpUoLE8sqq97pjyU9Vnb5GQr7TYUBAAtloTFocYpF"
    "Mzk5cUImHj0REeD0IoXGODDp54Q5dHF2PP3VObuVvNfBys5wxU39dpQbrCjNFY7jkRZLS2Yo"
    "/imCpbIQ0Trrug7NnOgRkYhXPhARIIKx1rroZNoJIiHUyHRFwYkkW9QqTuVT5/JDxnrWSuYh"
    "6LBqZYhpVNSVGRNRcc5Ca53rOmMMAhLx4AMRoHHWoASEiJlO0g8mXeUu/WonIBVVwS2qJmcu"
    "KR79keikLha4ZPRN/k8XsNITcMy2JaCIj4kCxNfDpCww1jnXI+Low0iMxjoz56mY9ZvUcqOE"
    "KNmo/aEgVaf5BKdClvQimcmYyh1KObktRBQhCX6cazM4DwGDggWIzlrr3DiGwMZaE0EIQKeD"
    "m/MbSFI6HAtaLVyNIlix5lak7CoZaVQNQEpEs8okpvhFFBq7obGWGAmMtQlNxDVXpY7Kpjhz"
    "YOrImOQ5Q5NqZfo6qYPa5kDJBwoFrU9DMb5E2CVFZXCpkPdpSTEMAQEMgzHWRGXMW2HilZtp"
    "vEDWVFyiGcHIc1zZKoo4O2Uk5c4VmUkFJYdFehLJKQGCAlCmNLOjYPJvollZBGDRGE1n2hzj"
    "9oiRUgpJrcGkqVQHMdjYNFW2SpLTgBKLDCWBm7f5KjdndpLObE4NavXoXBAx/8juhPgNooks"
    "DIqiGKHCp/RVEoytnPjFzqDpJaElQjUpSFEj0SR15AydshIJcokCxq/Ig9NljIzJEidYJmvf"
    "3dh/6ctvflocD8vFkev6rtuRIBCNVJmmFsmKC1Q6UyghI1bbZR2YRdjpTa0W0akyYWYjOk2K"
    "LAGHJzEBEzIzAk+HSmZkYma/GoZhScRPPLa3/9pzSER37y2++PrHz7767tc7fxGRc13X99b1"
    "xlodTSKFFw7Xx65YlRe15FRpS8UfAPB06modyqMGM8HUkw/ianBO/MXmmXcJBqbggx/9uPIh"
    "9M6+8sJTH763f+PN61f2dv8DEJ2mrumY9BEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=")
getbutton_blueData = button_blue.GetData
getbutton_blueImage = button_blue.GetImage
getbutton_blueBitmap = button_blue.GetBitmap

button_gray = PyEmbeddedImage(
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAAaCAIAAADOqG6yAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAADl0lE"
    "QVRYheWZOU4sMRCGXW23hkVCQoQkHAAJiSWflJgTwMm4AAlHIJsQAkICECFBo/ZML15eYJ7H"
    "4717hveEqKBll2vc9uff5TaAlBIhJKVkjFFKX19fZ7PZ09PT29tbVVWMMSEE+h1WFEVZlvv7"
    "+0dHR6enp2dnZ4eHhzs7O0VRAABCCOq6fnh4uL29fXl5AYDJZLK7u7u9vU0IAQAVtBHzdmU6"
    "dTn0UssfryY93lYppRCi7/u6rquqms/nAHB8fHxzc3N+fg7X19fPz8+MsbIsy7IEAMZY3/fr"
    "CCo+7a9VcmLiNAfFh6BE8JkFjDEhBGMshPj8/KSUbm1tTadT8v7+rrj0fd/3vW/uafuOCWfG"
    "e5vW7F8I0batKigmnPOPjw+CEFJpa6j9IEDxMG+8cjLGOOfaT9xxh2yEnkPBm413fzKCjtsk"
    "hOi6zkxHBP1NbO748t+ROaZ42KAFyIwf2r8uSykXi0XXdSYZj7J+Ip3R/XudnHNKadu2loZW"
    "YOm9mj+HDQL67v4z5da2bV3XZqrStoRlkvpVdPS+a5qGUurFpMxW1tB3rDOH0SdGZnzOeIQQ"
    "TdPM53PGGEqZraz/uMJu6zfRYYw1TdN1XUREXkvnrH+wBTbSub7kir/GOeecq+vtRm64Wadh"
    "XA7KhBBSSjVWPW5vZKSTpIX6dP3jvrTjtrIN9fUahXeEWjFNxApWVhSFWY3QyQE3DlCyPIIm"
    "MaEoWG7m4pyrq7UVbMZoi1cjzqR5p2c5k1xcp1WIQCSqDQAwxhhjhUDnQs0IAAj5kmHyeEry"
    "GgErSSpfSiE6oar2LLdhURSEEAXLlBLGOHQ25WTxjZDSlrn1cmB5q15S+tBcikUpCwDUmerF"
    "ZFYHfWetsxlzclY+nZxWk9TKRVqPWMFS92xzM4YyvbfqLaBN6CsnNyGHiOuJoPE+zaGunIbq"
    "jMMYI5+IQs9QFUV5DYIV2X2ZKSkflhlpK0sneISQzuXm/AeRGi20pIWUlZ+JMp+6AADquYRl"
    "vT4iq3ythRTnlq3RJBklMcVPtDgdq6rGtgJLVay2pL4iNHPwueW45ejIC0Kvh56g9UTGmplV"
    "5KwlAJDLy8v7+/uqqhaLhfrHmYUjpxAhGGeXRJakgwKisPwageuMkGKMqT8BHhwcTKdTEEJQ"
    "Smez2d3d3ePjo0KmPrjMM9E7K+88k2EjEpYJZU1PMvfpG7iUcm9v7+Li4urq6uTkZDKZ/AGs"
    "3amq94qX9AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==")
getbutton_grayData = button_gray.GetData
getbutton_grayImage = button_gray.GetImage
getbutton_grayBitmap = button_gray.GetBitmap

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
button_green_bright = PyEmbeddedImage(
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAAaCAIAAADOqG6yAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAIUUlE"
    "QVRYhY1YTastRxVdu7rvve/Fhxk8IgiKQgQDKookg0imOhGcOdI/IP4G/4cDZw6c6lhxGB2I"
    "hCBElBANCD5Q8/LyzOnT3VXLQe2v6nNu8FzuOd3V1VW111577V0lJAEAbK2t2/qfj/717j/e"
    "eeuvv//38yfnbVnOp33fewcCIAjaTfpQ/+1OEA2HrukjcSX3dvrkF//v59K/ZGyxeQUApml6"
    "cPvgdn744guPv/7ya1/+wtcef/qlu9uHRYqIAJDlfPrTe3/8xW9/+ta7b251nafbT909enj3"
    "6Ga+EQj7B/2r/0AbFDXDacCv3whAgfCKAWKrxwGpvizrLYffg5m5a0JC1DbxaUSfSx8/7iU/"
    "gogIya2uz08fPfvv02U9FZFXPv+NH377x6++8ob85Gc/+t07v1m20025vZ1eKCJ725f1tNet"
    "sSlACRYDCd4EiN4aiQZz3YhksCTrHB2zXgRXhomnAhm7yfF5Bt4BSlOJT+2N0sft/1OZb+e7"
    "ucwkP/z4g+fLs6lML3/2K/P7//zbeV1rZeX51M6ZSoHOgFf8woHrkytaoviN4CQMsr/zsxwU"
    "YX380ZtGNwRE8YK/NTpigC6gGiHbpa7r2gPrtJ72re6of37v7bmRrbHVpnHWNOCMUz3w+l1E"
    "nWmXQFSiWtCAHb9wMSkCZsM4RhIIUX5KbrExqPNoH6rRZHNoGfMJxf0HEVuN0d5ZpqNGXPZP"
    "4vpe92Vdaq0ACspMko2tY8TmPDKYnFWDiHcEnVRN7dRo7GrFFH+0hwIJlRM4rEIHzCAjCIqy"
    "guwgq0sIejQRAlKoTupDQSA2fn8zfNvnI41o2kUIijpZICC5nJdt3QkKBWgziNbYGgGwgQpY"
    "1nInCIJc6jBD0UyhRp8u2g1FBG6ourpWCE0CVMY54bzNREDEQADYYdHZDWxdlnT0OkdIpx/F"
    "b82iTiyKodk5S6zr+bSc1FwQ4MwGT26mV7HQzmhTrO5q6S8cSgJ6Aoyv7j0m0zuflOccgkbf"
    "COC65d3A0DgTADVA3Gx4oJkLu8rpXJ3r1ky6TpH9vhNN1M7zsiznpRncnZKzEcZtD86g4+2z"
    "9pXT5EN80epM82KORolng8obpgQcDBvOmZUp5nLo/jdiZ6E3cJK2s3M79FCvaZDB1YxCcK/1"
    "dPp432saUgk891urAYqIskxBd1l2ibKwJm0QMQKKriJQ8fRmeSCruoNhuuV8ihnDIaYwA9YZ"
    "zeBYB4ACD1mdpwWMTtcIia3up2WxIlwbGyILz74ydZdFPtLcVH1RmXTp7S+FzySQyM43q2Ld"
    "DP8P/HGI8wqCNpJCT0asEmMP1Ax3C0x83Ecgsde6LOd9370i8q5dnbvNJOdkkGbNUKOeIUya"
    "SQs9F1mxIBQMwmnrK8ansCTqnIwGxfk1IpuIZBVlDjuYBCSocujHTsISKASttX3d123b96oS"
    "6CKaFIGuojb+7C4Qq2tMvkUFuuMvYoxI0aHrUwCvbvDG3cuVy1R9Jj4cILNOiWSXvcHYSmg9"
    "1Kr/NTYnQVr/sGZ6osgSaZec44VhW9AZpXslc3wvXEqvoZxIqgG9nuWh9kgLGvC9wDTqs+Oj"
    "q0YZW1KLWmTM8lol42IlTWhoeqP3oQsnQ2Z6t9mRQoiBFR/CXo/5SATIVltrrbZGhsgnk0RQ"
    "IGCRw4PB9EFkPulzAZ4zO0c4h0cWPhZkjA4JgezLI0nN3GGtMxyjImUq1ouubwAq677vrTaV"
    "OgEmyOSZ5YI51lhMkG1jx/H5CMJ1Tl2DModHoKBlmmr30K7oMEpmS94JSq2KrAgGj8oydyWQ"
    "gmku883kAk+ysu37vtedICaUyTYSSUBj8XLkSiAyyO+o3Qco7onBw7OAlQ6HjulbfajDMxMt"
    "uBKUMVrLkwh1f+C4i1DmXt+IoEwy3ZSOfGPbtq22ysJS4ABZGo7AhIz26e7LvDMcNQzAXSXX"
    "/fikmLNGkkMf31b0gKC2eCoMaKgimwgoCZd0AbCh7X3P2JlVAGK6KfNtgWDbt20/Y+I0dSSE"
    "LuY2mO+BEVsKRTPIYzrIVAECB2qNkB03UQfsEpHD5ljXgTLeqAARZLeV+nqM4C3D6yRYoecE"
    "xKxlQ5FpkvmmbHWtspYZQ3SHLWafb3vcVFW+MUfm7BEwjQEoF3AdARObO1IgcwRdxlS3nQD7"
    "XkdGNAWUSNcEWOziMJRwIyuEKOhhWCCUMgtLa61OczE6E7YdMK13Z3i5gUvIAPpxkf5n7BIC"
    "14IxnORb6vQj91CJGSaFyvJRAsVebADKoTGxlWJ2NqLsQINQZnjOKsJSy9w3ejKS2nLxSC5d"
    "/FBWBjqAbRVcpy6T9OVF/lxQOgqCQ7yoSNHQ0a2hK5dRUdSqSW9dszwPSCeajVzBtjYAhTJL"
    "ESmdBk2KlFJgZzawc7SsWbZ1VgsZxgcuiomeV1rxFngl7C64dh9SKQPKGIMWuH0/wxyDsV0j"
    "Jc4FtOehdPBghziIEGFrEylSNBv2s9SCMksBWsBEO4H0SeNAso8/VgUh6gApJUeZ6LoSXheb"
    "xOHjlUnXxjhhxeAg2uFhCsw45dMVdxBFHDU9LuxRE5oo5o+4aLJPIDhB5m9+6fUnT99/tjzd"
    "Tm2+K9NtKZpA+imQHVGQifsSspVLh/BHTCwOixAoRjXECZNcxwqwSoUKiFjoSJanDqbnasef"
    "IQ3OEhBFSBax5WZROBxXgMKd29oK8ODhoze++h1prX34/INf/+FXv3zz539/8pe97WWayixl"
    "BkpHCURTodD49PNU9/ax/LZTWrvNy0ng5pVeQJVeHNHJfSwIO2sSQv7WmEQyItlV4n8Ed7SK"
    "WmtB+dxLX/zet37w3de///jFz/wP8WUTUVqRAEEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=")
getbutton_green_brightData = button_green_bright.GetData
getbutton_green_brightImage = button_green_bright.GetImage
getbutton_green_brightBitmap = button_green_bright.GetBitmap

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
button_red = PyEmbeddedImage(
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAAaCAIAAADOqG6yAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAEWElE"
    "QVRYheWYvW4bRxDH/7NckpIQGKBgGAhUygiUIk1cOA9gwKU7w5VfwG+RPqUfwKVbl4YfIG5U"
    "pBIgqAwCGDL1AYo83u3OpFjece92b+8o0QYSLRaL2eFwb+bHmbk7kogAEBEuisV0en5ycvbp"
    "09+fP09PT7PLS2sMRHBPBtFA653JZP/x44OnTw+fPXt4dLS7v6+GQyICQPPz87/ev//z7dvL"
    "szOyVu/tjR880Lu7g9GIiEC0LT8ANM+qDveuQjElIh/XbCg0ptqhbRcNXRJmLop8Nsu+fl1e"
    "XzPR5PDwtzdvfnn1iv44OJh9+SLW0niMnR0AyHNkmTBHfN1whJFHNNEAYuH1Oi2hSZqtlURQ"
    "CuMxhkMCiuvr4uICRD88ekS/DwbMDBEmEiIASoQ2Lb0NPbt1SKkgt+qGEDGRiJibGzufQ0Qp"
    "pSHiupIqhb7j1gF8L7Ibn+ZpCFAAW2vyfIVIRKP/aC+c7QbZUZjf4EeKng8Rs1yubnFEADRc"
    "F0/k1BZTo6fZdy+66PnFYlHM56h6N1Ess+4rHT+n8pubfDYTa+GNdc9afS9M0W8MaLun3b3B"
    "2TzPrq6sa1XVaPYsR6oB6B7QqZQmy5ZXV7Yo2pqS9r9JSv0nouqp6WUmYpbLfDYzWdb5MFDv"
    "WX4Z/v/oACByL3ZmsTCLxaYvc11luKG7m7W8alupYvGvzqmU/kf1C4gbzMIs1rK1bIybwnz3"
    "l9zy0SFWhp101l6LgFmYmRluOmUVkQgBguBdzH27h6OSlMXbhpotDCIQlXdDhywoQ3IQncKF"
    "ai0bI9YSM7zgqZTDNSpEt+GQ0qwNgQQr6sgaBv5sHJX0w90NHSNAEWmlyAO0EkTYGM5zMDul"
    "LgPwAXWS8rmEjBqaMIBoZoWkQkZRodpyoGygLP3zMouIRkQjojUmQBwja5WHpgEoKifWKJq2"
    "/JKWbRuszmxq4+KzayjZKf3nLAKGROMSlhQFL5dg1gGmEFCC111gJZIrnVCJVAoNOLb1pwHy"
    "0qaERTR0mSXCy6UUhRaJYupk14aprYu18UqnVVtOIYDCMX1VfdFU8rcE5OWl1z1rSDQU4SxT"
    "xpBHKqzBzkTrU5ttjMIRrb4+LalnoUUZcZ1X2bPKMRAZ5PnAI9XAFFJTASBVh9InxRLIEk0q"
    "XX2JmYDCMcF67unqn7+BtbokpQIcoRBO1ZVlCPAlSEUZ3Q5QG5RK5vatcR5Wjw7uT2RlrfZI"
    "qQBQW6L1qdPOkmwgk0COcomSSuROHzpS3QEBBgaNMhQAIspaHQOk6oDaCDbMeva4KK8oqVvQ"
    "6cnFX6lsUqrU+I1F//zy5enHj/nFxZR5F9j1iETRqABcFF8CImLgfF7RDtWnrKLxh6sTVMmi"
    "Wqm+ZSAHLoFCKT2Z/PT8OTFzNp2efPhw/O7dP8fHxXyumUfACND1eDqLqLOXR+37DAkI+ijb"
    "+KaNQwM3DVAAOcBK6b29H588+fX166MXL3Ymk38BAbsi18hyJgEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=")
getbutton_redData = button_red.GetData
getbutton_redImage = button_red.GetImage
getbutton_redBitmap = button_red.GetBitmap

class StaticBmpButton(wx.PyControl):

    def __init__(self, parent, width, height, bmpNormal, bmpHover, bmpClick, bmpOff, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="", pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.NO_BORDER, validator=wx.DefaultValidator, name="StaticBmpButton"):

        wx.PyControl.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=id, pos=pos, size=size, style=wx.NO_BORDER, validator=validator, name=name)

        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.bmpNormal = bmpNormal
        self.bmpHover = bmpHover
        self.bmpClick = bmpClick
        self.bmpOff = bmpOff
        self._InitBuffer()
        self._InitPaintObjects()
        self._BindEvents()
        self._SetProperties(label)
        self.SetInitialSize(size)
        self.InheritAttributes()

    def _SetProperties(self, label):
        self._label = label
        self._leftButtonDown = False
        self.SetLabelColor(wx.WHITE)
        self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_HAND))
        self.SetFont(wx.Font(pointSize=10, family=wx.FONTFAMILY_SWISS, style=wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, weight=wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL))
        self._hasFocus = False

    def DoGetBestSize(self):
        best = wx.Size(self.width, self.height)
        i = self.height * 0.577
        self.ratio = int(i)
        self.CacheBestSize(best)
        return best

    def GetLabel(self):
        return self._label

    def SetLabelColor(self, color):
        self._labelColor = color

    def _InitPaintObjects(self):
        self._pen = wx.Pen(wx.BLACK, 2, wx.SOLID)
        self._brush = wx.Brush(wx.BLACK, wx.SOLID)

    def _BindEvents(self):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self._OnEraseBackground)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self._OnSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self._OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self._OnMouseClickDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self._OnMouseHover)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self._OnMouseClickUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self._OnLeaveWindow)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self._OnMouseClickDown)

    def Enable(self, enable=True):
        wx.PyControl.Enable(self, enable)
        self.Refresh()

    def _OnLeaveWindow(self, evt):
        self._leftButtonDown = False
        self._hasFocus = False
        self.Refresh()

    def _OnMouseHover(self, evt):
        if self.IsEnabled():
            self._hasFocus = True
            self.Refresh()

    def _OnMouseClickDown(self, evt):
        if self.IsEnabled():
            self._leftButtonDown = True
            self.Refresh()

    def _OnMouseClickUp(self, evt):
        if self.IsEnabled():
            buttonEvent = wx.CommandEvent(wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, self.GetId())
            buttonEvent.SetEventObject(self)
            self.GetEventHandler().ProcessEvent(buttonEvent)
            self._leftButtonDown = False
            self.Refresh()

    def _OnPaint(self, evt):
        self._Draw(wx.BufferedPaintDC(self, self._buffer))

    def _OnSize(self, evt):
        self._InitBuffer()
        self.Refresh()
        evt.Skip()

    def _OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
        pass

    def _InitBuffer(self):
        self._buffer = wx.EmptyBitmap(self.width, self.height)

    def _Draw(self, dc):
        dc = wx.GCDC(dc)
        self._DrawBox(dc)
        self._DrawLabel(dc)

    def _DrawLabel(self, dc):
        dc.SetFont(self.GetFont())
        tw, th = dc.GetTextExtent(self._label)
        tposx, tposy = ((self.width/2)-(tw/2), (self.height/2)-(th/2))

        dc.SetTextForeground(wx.Color(0,0,0,75))
        dc.DrawText(self._label, tposx+1, tposy+1)

        if self.IsEnabled():
            dc.SetTextForeground(self._labelColor)
        else:
            dc.SetTextForeground(wx.Color(255,255,255,75))

        dc.DrawText(self._label, tposx, tposy)

    def _DrawBox(self, dc):
        if self.IsEnabled():
            if self._leftButtonDown:
                dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmpClick, 0, 0, True)
            elif self._hasFocus:
                dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmpHover, 0, 0, True)
            else:
                dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmpNormal, 0, 0, True)
        else:
            dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmpOff, 0, 0, True)

class _DemoWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, size=(640,480))

        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Color(255,255,255))

        bmpNormal = getbutton_blueBitmap()
        bmpHover = getbutton_green_brightBitmap()
        bmpClick = getbutton_redBitmap()
        bmpOff = getbutton_grayBitmap()
        self.test_button1 = StaticBmpButton(self, 100, 26, bmpNormal, bmpHover, bmpClick, bmpOff, -1, label="Hello")
        self.test_button2 = StaticBmpButton(self, 100, 26, bmpNormal, bmpHover, bmpClick, bmpOff, -1, label="Connect")
        self.test_button3 = StaticBmpButton(self, 100, 26, bmpNormal, bmpHover, bmpClick, bmpOff, -1, label="Disconnect")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton1, self.test_button1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton2, self.test_button2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCloseButton, self.test_button3)

        self.test_button3.Disable()

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.Add(self.test_button1, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        hbox.Add(self.test_button2, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        hbox.Add(self.test_button3, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        vbox.AddStretchSpacer(1)
        vbox.Add(hbox, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        vbox.AddStretchSpacer(1)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Fit()

        self.SetSize((640, 480))

    def OnButton1(self, evt):
        print evt.GetEventObject().GetLabel()
        self.test_button2.Enable()
        self.test_button3.Enable()

    def OnButton2(self, evt):
        self.test_button2.Disable()
        self.test_button3.Enable()

    def OnCloseButton(self, evt):
        self.test_button3.Disable()
        self.test_button2.Enable()

def _demo():
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    _DemoWindow().Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _demo()
```

Comment: Thanks for the lead and the link. I was hoping I could do it more simply by just subclassing the StaticBitmap and adding an attribute "value" to the subclass. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Also thanks for the StaticBmpButton(wx.PyControl) code. However I don't see how that will let me assign a bitmap to the control?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to GolfDope for your comment and solution. But what I was looking for was a way to use the built-in widgets of wxPython.

After searching through numerous questions and answers it looks like what I needed was the GenStaticBitmap. It looks like this works and does what I needed. If it proves not to be robust enough I'll be forced to do something with the PyControl as above.
Here's what seems to work:

```
import  wx.lib.statbmp as gen_statbmp

#  (gen_statbmp.GenStaticBitmap).__init__(self, parent, ID, bitmap, pos, size, style, name)
########################################################################
class MyBitmapButton(gen_statbmp.GenStaticBitmap):
    """Subclasses a GenStaticBitmap and adds button like functionality 
        requires the three bitmap images needed for on,off and hover"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, bmpoff,bmpon,bmphover):
        """Constructor"""
        gen_statbmp.GenStaticBitmap.__init__(self, parent, ID, bmpoff)
        self.bmpoff=bmpoff
        self.bmpon=bmpon
        self.bmphover=bmphover
        self.SetBitmap(bmpoff)
        self.state='off'
        # Bind Mouse Actions to button
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW,self.On_Hover)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW,self.On_Leave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,self.On_Click)

    # Define Mouse Actions and Button Response
    def On_Hover(self,event):
        self.SetBitmap(self.bmphover)

    def On_Leave(self,event):
        #print 'on enter button state is',self.state
        if self.state=='on':
            self.SetBitmap(self.bmpon)
            self.state='on'
        if self.state=='off':
            self.SetBitmap(self.bmpoff)
            self.state='off'
        #print 'on leave button state is',self.state

    def On_Click(self,event):
        self.SetBitmap(self.bmpon)
        event.Skip()
########################################################################
```